# Distance of a line

Tags: geometry

I am asked to " Find the distance from the origin to the point $(7,4)$".

I know that I have to use the formula for the length of a line and midpoint but I am unsure of what the question is asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: Use the distance formula, which in general assumes the following form: Given two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, then the distance between these two points is: 
$$d=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$$ Here the points are $(0,0)$ (the origin) and $(7,4)$ therefore we get:

$$d=\sqrt{(7-0)^2+(4-0)^2}=\sqrt{49+16}=\sqrt{65}\text{ units.}$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the Pythagorean theorem! Draw a right triangle triangle with the line segment from $(0,0)$ to  $(7,4)$ as the hypotnuse and the $x,y$ axes as the legs.

Don't let the co ordinates trip you up, you still have everything you know about geometry to draw from, the co ordinates are in some sense just a handy way to talk about it.

Comment: Very nice answer because of the advice that coordinates doesn't mean we can't use normal geometry. Many coordinates questions can be reduced in calculation if we consider them as an euclidean geo question. Similarly sometimes euclidean geo questions break when we apply coordinates.